# Creating Clothes using the Mask Method

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I was trying to create clothes for my female character but when I create a mask and extract it, parts of the torso do not get extracted properly and some parts get joined to the neck.

Here is how it looks. In sculpt mode, I used *Mask Brush* to paint the area to be clothed and went to the mask options from the top menu and chose *Mask Extract*. Then unchecked *Extract As Solid* and extracted the mask.

But some parts of the torso did not get extracted with the mask and some parts of the mask extraction joined to the neck.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you checked if the face orientation is correct? Have you applied the scale to the model? (A negative scale can flip normals). Make sure that it's not parented to a rig or something. Had you left the *Project to Sculpt option* enabled? (it's by default). This seems to work like the shrinkwrap modifier. I've tried it on my own model which was parented to a rig and still scaled up. With this option enabled the result was that the shirt got crumbled on the head. Without this option, the shirt was ok but scaled up.

Comment: Yes it's parented to a rig

Comment: Thanks a lllooooooooottttttt, It worked!!!!!

Comment: Cheers! :-) So the rig and this *Project to Sculpt* option caused the problem? Feel free to post an answer to your question.

Comment: I don't know about Project To Sculpt Option, but it was the rig being parented to the mesh caused the problem, I deleted the rig and now everything is solved